# Retrieving the Names of Files in a txt file

Tags: command-line

How to Retrieve the Names of Files to a txt file??

Comment: Do you mean ls > files.txt ?

Comment: please elaborate your q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute

```
ls -1 >filename
```

this will redirect the output in the file with the filename given.

For the content of a folder:

```
ls -1 foldername >filename
```

Comment: How can do the same to contents of folders?

Comment: ls -R >filename

Comment: And if you want to see directory structure, I like the `tree` command.

Comment: if you want the content of a folder add the folder name to it